# How to append text on a jtextarea

Tags: java, swing, append, actionlistener, jtextarea

When I push a button, I want to show text in a JTextArea before executing a method. I use jTextArea.append() and jTextArea.settext() but the text appears after method execution. My code:

```
    //...JTextArea jTextArea;
    JButton btnGo = new JButton("Start");
    btnGo.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        jTextArea.append("line before\n");
        myMethodFromOtherClass();
        jTextArea.append("line after\n");
        }
    }
```

Any sugestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actionPerformed() method is dispatched by the EDT (Event dispatcher thread) which handles all GUI-related events. Updates performed within the method will not be updated until the `actionPerformed()` method completes execution. To solve this, perform `myMethodFromOtherClass()` in another thread, and only queue the final update event (`jTextArea.append("line after\n");`) after the method completes execution in the second thread.

A crude demonstration of this is shown below:

```
JButton btnGo = new JButton("Start");
btnGo.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        //Leave this here
        jTextArea.append("line before\n");

        //Create new thread to start method in
        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                myMethodFromOtherClass();

                //Queue the final append in the EDT's event queue
                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
                    public void run(){
                        jTextArea.append("line after\n");
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        //Start the thread
        t.start();
    }
}
```

Should a more elegant solution be devised please look at [SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) which is based on a very similar procedure but with more advanced features.

Comment: So long as the "other" method does not interact with the GUI in which case a SwingWorker may be a better choice

Comment: @MadProgrammer Yeah... Note my word "crude". I guess I'll add mention to SwingWorker in my answer. Thanks.

Comment: The answers not wrong, the question is missing content to be 100% sure of which solution to choose ;)